# Scaling a subpanel while resizing

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, netbeans-6.9

I am working on a project with using Swing. Recently, I ve encountered a weird problem that I can't figure out how to solve. Had a look at similar questions and tried to use layouts for frame but it didnt solve the problem. All design is done with using free design. I am using Netbeans.

My question is, I want every panel to be resized properly. Without losing half of the panel and buttons on the screen.

Also tried to call pack() method in the componentListener(another solution that i saw here) but it didnt work neither. Here are some pictures of my project.

Regards.

[image]

After resizing:

[image]

Comment: What exactly is your question and how do you expect your window to behave on scaling?

Comment: Have you looked through [this guide](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/quickstart-gui.html#adding_components) which explains, amongst other things, how to use Automatic Component Positioning (Snapping)?

Comment: just looked through, didn't find anything useful.

Comment: sounds like a layout issue - show a SSCCE

Comment: So you tried snapping your components to the dotted alignment guideline on the right window side and scaling did not work properly afterwards? If so, please try to create an entirely new frame with the correct snappings - in case some other modifications were already applied in this frame.

Comment: Most likely you are using absolute positioning. Don't do that, but use layout managers instead. They'll take care of the repositioning of the components for you.

Comment: Thanks for the answers firstly, @MichaelLang tried what you have suggested, but still have the problem. kiheru, I will try to resign with using layout managers along with align. By the way, already tried box layout and it didn't work.

Comment: There is no need to use only one layout manager (even though there are some powerful enough for that). You can nest layouts, so that you don't need to solve the entire window layout problem at once. Maybe using `BorderLayout` for the overall design, and a `BoxLayout` for the top row.